# Integrating wire-elements/modal with laravel-filament admin panel

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament

I've tried integrating wire-elements/modal with the filamentphp admin package exactly as the example in the docs. But when I add the example code into my serviceprovider the /admin and all subroutes return a 404. I've Installed wire-elements/modal with composer and here is my code from AppServiceProvider.php:

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Filament\Facades\Filament;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        Filament::registerRenderHook(
            'body.end',
            fn (): string => Blade::render('@livewire(\'livewire-ui-modal\')'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: It was fixed by putting the code in the boot() method instead of the register() method.